# How do I get values from database table as an array and return it in dropdownlist?

Tags: mysql, arrays

I have a table with columns (id, name) whereas in name, I have name of months (january, february...) I want to take all this name and return it in dropdownlist where I can take one of month. I have this function in my model:

```
public function getMonths()
{
    $month= Months::find()
->asArray()
->all();

     for($monthNum = self::MY_START; $monthNum <= self::MY_MONTH; $monthNum++){
   return $month[$monthNum];
    }

}
```

Now it only returns me one month (2 february ). What should I do to return in this dropdown list only name of these months?

Comment: which framework you are using ...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate drop-down list input with values from DB table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221444/generate-drop-down-list-input-with-values-from-db-table)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Yii2 you can simply use the dropdownlist in view

```
<?php
 use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
?>

<?= Html::activeDropDownList($model, 'your_month_id',
   ArrayHelper::map(Months::find()->all(), 'id', 'name')) ?>
```